# Could not load file or assembly - when all dependency present and all sign present and assembly loading to GAC

Tags: deployment, com, .net-4.8

I try to deploy COM-object to my server, I have deployed to this server a lot of objects and always all going fine, but not at this time.

Firstly, COM-object registered successfully and ProgID is present.

[image: ProgID present]

Secondary, all dependency is present and loading successfully.

[image: All dependency present]

Third point, I checked all sign and all sign is present.

[image: All sing is present]

Forth point I add all library to GAC.

[image: All assembly adding to GAC]

Test is ordinary and no matter, this is simple call my COM-object.

It's look as all checkpoint done and test must be working. However, I see error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp, Version=1.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

[image: Trouble]

I can not understand this trouble. What going wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all sign is present", but the error is clear: "A strongly-named assembly is required". The program you execute requires this assembly to have a strong name and apparently it does not have one. You can check strong names with the sn.exe tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool This is unrelated to COM. Also, assemblies in the GAC must have a strong name.

Comment: Maybe my trouble in flag of assembly, named ComVisible.

Comment: ComVisible is related to COM, but has nothing to do with the strong name issue.

Comment: I'm sure, that this issue related with ComVisible, I try to rebuild Assembly with ComVisible flag = true, but can not understand trouble with VS2022 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824202/assembly-information-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified" is another error. You're making confusion with all these errors. They may be indirectly related in the end but the root cause of each is different. And no, COM is *not* related with strong name issues. What may be related is some people want to put COM objects written in .NET in the GAC and to put a .NET library in the GAC it must be strong signed, but there's no direct relation between COM and strong names. If you are so "sure", you shouldn't ask for help on this forum but fix the issue by yourself.