# Assembly information - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: .net-assembly, visual-studio-2022

I have absolutely no idea, what does it means? I only press OK in assembly information in order to specify Assembly Version.

What paths is absent? And what operation VS2022 can not finished? It looks as Visual Studio programmers what is useful error messages are.

[image: Assembly information The system cannot find the path specified.]

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem and for me it was a VB project, and when you modify the AssemblyInfo, it tries to write the AssemblyInfo.vb file to the .\My Projects\AssemblyInfo.vb. Normally when you create a fresh project, I think this folder is created automatically so VS assumes it's there and gives you this error if the folder is missing.

In my case the folder was not checked in to git, so when I checked out the project the folder was not there. I would assume the same is true for c# projects, except the folder expected would be .\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.

All I had to do was create the "My Projects" folder at the root of my project and the error went away. It appears you are using c#, so try creating a "Properties" folder at the root of your project and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what path Vs2022 can not found and what operation VS2022 can not complete, but manually add CS-file with needed attributes solve this issue.

[image: Solver issue with assembly information]